# innerHTML not printing. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am not exactly new at coding, 
But I am definitely an amateur (especially in Javascript), and I have just started a new project for personal purpose.

I can not seem to get my Javascript to print out my answer, and I do not want to move on with the project until I figure it out, because it is going to have more complicated calculations as I work on it.

My code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Enter Your Macros</p>
        <p>Fats</p>
        <input type="number" name="fats" id="fatInput"/><br>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button><br>
        <p id="todaysFat"></p>
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var f = document.getElementById("fatInput").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("todaysFat").innerHTML = f;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for all of the help

Comment: you get the value of an `input` element with its `.value` property, not `.innerHTML`

Comment: `fatInput` is an input element, they use `value` not `innerHTML`. You should also use `textContent` instead on `todaysFat` since you're not altering any HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Change the innerhtml to value in the first line.
See the below code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var f = document.getElementById("fatInput").value;
  document.getElementById("todaysFat").innerHTML = f;
}
```

```html
<p>Enter Your Macros</p>
<p>Fats</p>
<input type="number" name="fats" id="fatInput" />
<br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
<br>
<p id="todaysFat"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
function myFunction() {
            var f = document.getElementById("fatInput").value;
            document.getElementById("todaysFat").innerHTML = f;
}
```

Comment: Please always add some explanation to your code...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the innerHTML your want but the value of the INPUT.
So that's .value  not innerHTML.

eg..

```
var f = document.getElementById("fatInput").value;
```